# Discrete Math Recursive Definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I am just unsure if I did this question right and would just like to check.

**Question:** A bit-string is simply a finite sequence of zeroes and ones. For the purposes of this problem, strings will always have length $\ge 1$, i.e. no zero-length strings.

Let $A_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ that have no two consecutive zeros. Thus $A_1=2$ and $A_2=3$ (strings $01$, $10$ and $11$).

Give recursive definitions for $A_n$.

**My Answer(s):**
$$A(n+1) = A(n)+A(n-1),$$
$$A(n) = A(n-1)+A(n-2).$$

Comment: Your recurrence is correct, though a complete answer would explain the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems true.  I assume $A_n$ to be the actual sets not just their respective size.  $A_{n+2}$ equals the disjoint union of the set $X$ of sequences ending in $1$ and the set $Y$ of sequences ending in $10$.  $A_{n+1}$ maps bijectively on $X$ via $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})\mapsto(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1},1)$ and $A_{n}$ on $Y$ via $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1,\ldots,x_n,1,0)$.